# Can I clear a webapp in Chrome?

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome, manifest

I've written a webapp that has a manifest that includes all the javascript and images that it requires. Unfortunately, even when I change the manifest file, it doesn't seem to reload the javascript.

Is there a way to delete the webapp completely from Chrome? Clearing the browser cache doesn't seem to work.

I'm running Chrome 5.0.375.55 on a Mac.

Any help very gratefully received.

Answer (score 160):

Adding a get parameter like `?foo=12345` will treat your file as a different one and therefore recache it, but NOT clear any cache for the existing file.

Type:

```
chrome://appcache-internals/
```

and you'll get Lucky :)

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, you should mark it as accepted (that checkmark right below the answer votes)

Comment: This works, but why is it necessary?  Following all the guidelines for  making an offline app, but chrome alone seems to ignore manifest updates.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has some really good documentation on this, it is a bit tricky to get going but it does make the whole manifest process way more transparent. In addition, I find Safari (esp. Mobile Safari) shows these event responses more consistently than Firefox; not sure about Chrome though it should be pretty close to Safari.

The root of your question though:

1. Empty the manifest or add/remove a file to the manifest
2. load the app
3. re-add the manifest
4. Re-load app. This is dirty way but I recommend taking the time to read though and implement the JS and so you can see for sure the manifest is getting updated.

Google has a good post [here](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/05/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-part-2.html).

Basically you can build a series of `if else` tests with the `window.applicationCache.status` for a clear look at what the system is doing.

From Apple:

For example, you get the DOMApplicationCache object as follows:

```
cache = window.applicationCache;
```

You can check the status of the application cache as follows:

```
if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)...
```

If the application cache is in the UPDATEREADY state, then you can update it by sending it the update() message as follows:

```
window.applicationCache.update();
```

If the update is successful, swap the old and new caches as follows:

```
window.applicationCache.swapCache();
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it cached server side as well? Try adding a get parameter like ?foo=12345 to the url and see if you get the updated file.

Answer (score 0):

No (as far as I know)

It seems that people want the questioner to accept an answer, but no one has actually answered the question.  I am no expert, but I have been searching a lot, and I think "No" is correct, and answers the question as posed.